# ler arquivo de texto e gerar listas para cada linha com separação de elementos

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Citação em python, eu tenho por exemplo as seguintes linhas em um arquivo de texto:

1,julian,0,5,6,7,8,9

2,ana,01,9,5,6,8,1

e queria gerar listas:

lista1 = [1,'julian',0,5,6,7,8,9]

lista2 = [2,'ana',01,9,5,6,8,1]

> Citação pois eu preciso relacionar depois através de uma equação os elementos depois dos nomes então precisava separar os elementos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> O nome do arquivo que você quer ler é CSV (*comma-separated values*), que significa "valores separados por vírgula.

Pegando um arquivo chamado `meu.csv`, com exatamente este conteúdo:

```
1,julian,0,5,6,7,8,9
2,ana,01,9,5,6,8,1
```

Você poderá passar esse conteúdo para uma lista, usando o seguinte código:

```
import csv
lista = [] # você só precisa de uma lista - ela é uma matriz multidimensional

with open('meu.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    # o nome 'spamreader' abaixo é só exemplo, poderia ser qq. coisa
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',') # separe por vírgula

    # o módulo csv detectará novas linhas automaticamente
    for linha in spamreader:
        lista.append(linha)

# os elementos começam ser contados em zero, i.e. lista[0][1] == 'julian'
print(lista[1]) # imprime a linha 2 da lista, inteira
print(lista[1][1]) # imprime apenas o segundo item da linha 2
```

> Resultado:
>   [image: resultado da execução do código]

Answer (score 1):

```
f = open("texto.txt",'r')
texto = f.readlines()

x = 0

while x < len(texto):
    if texto[x] == "\n":
        local = texto.index(texto[x])
        texto.pop(local)
    else:
        texto[x] = texto[x].split(',')
        x += 1

# Esse for abaixo aqui é só para tirar o "\n" em algumas strings, é opcional.

for i in texto:
    local = texto.index(i) # Local do i em texto
    for b in i:
        local2 = texto[local].index(b) # Local2 do b em i ( local )
        if "\n" in b:
            texto[local][local2] = b.replace("\n",'') # Substitui o valor de acordo com "local" e "local2"

lista1, lista2 = texto
print("lista1 =",lista1)
print("lista2 =",lista2)
```

**Saída:**

```
>>> lista1 = ['1', 'julian', '0', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
>>> lista2 = ['2', 'ana', '01', '9', '5', '6', '8', '1']
```

**Saída sem o for opcional**

Basicamente a mesma coisa

```
>>> lista1 = ['1', 'julian', '0', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9\n']
>>> lista2 = ['2', 'ana', '01', '9', '5', '6', '8', '1']
```

Answer (score 1):

Vou dar uma resposta somente para a conversão do array, as duas outras respostas dos colegas mostram como ler o arquivo linha a linha. Primeiro, usa uma função para converter o valor para inteiro, se não conseguir, retorna a própria string.

```
def converte(elem):
    try:
        int(elem)
    except:
        elem
```

Usando um for-comprehension, pode iterar nos valores. Pense no for-comprehension como se fosse um conjunto matemático.

```
[converte(i) for i in string.split(linha, ',')]
```

Esse código poderia ser escrito: "Seja i pertencente ao conjunto dos elementos que foram separados por vírgula, faça um novo conjunto aplicando a função converte.".